# How to connect my new docker image to MySQL docker image and run both together

Tags: c#, .net, docker

i just created my first  .netcore api with docker. i added a docker compose file and add then service to depend on MySQL. The application works fine if the run with docker compose on my visual studio community and i can see the docker compose file with my api and mysql container running on my docker desktop. I pushed my docker api image to docker hub to test it, so i delete everything created by the docker compose and visual studio. I pulled my docker image successfully and used the run command, which worked and I can see my application running on the docker desktop and I can access the swagger in the browser. The issue now is that I cannot see the MySQL like previously under the same docker compose . it just my image running and I tried using one of my end point and I got 500 error,
{
"message": "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."
} .

Please how can i connect my new image to the mysql docker image.

DOCKER COMPOSE FILE

```
version: '3.4'

volumes:
 datafiles:

services:
  database:
     image: mysql:latest
     volumes:
        - datafiles:/var/lib/mysql
        - "~/sql-scripts/setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
     restart: always
     environment: 
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 123#
        MYSQL_USER: root
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: 123#
        MYSQL_DATABASE: System

  trackingsystem-backend:
      image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}trackingsystembackend
     build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: TrackingSystem-Backend/Dockerfile
     depends_on: 
       - database
```

Comment: Indentation in yaml files is really important and yours looks weird around the definition of your database container. Is this really how it looks?

Comment: @HansKilian I have adjusted the indentation. This is how it looks

Comment: How does your connection string look? Rather than `localhost:3306`, you should connect to `database:3306`

Comment: @HansKilian    "Database": "server=database; port=3306; database=System; user=root; password=123#; Persist Security Info=False; Connect Timeout=300"

Comment: @HansKilian i can connect successfully when i start the app from visual studio. but how do i connect when i pull my image to a new laptop. and run it. how do i include mysql image and connect them

Comment: You can always pull the mysql image from docker hub. If you want your own image to be available to others, you need to push it to a docker repository somewhere.

Comment: @HansKilian I already made my image available on docker hub and a friend pulled it and also pulled the MySQL image. how do we combine both image to work together. Both of them are running dependently and cannot communicated with each other. How do you make two separate image in different container communicate. my new api image and the mysql image that it depends on.

Comment: Are you running each container individually using ```docker run``` or are you running the docker-compose file by using ```docker-compose up```. If you run ```docker-compose up -d``` and then run ```docker ps``` do you see the mysql contianer running?

Comment: @HansKilian i am using docker run. here is the error after using docker-compose up -d on the other laptop.                                                                Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any
        parent. Are you in the right directory?

        Supported filenames: docker-compose.yml, docker-compose.yaml, compose.yml, compose.yaml

Comment: @HansKilian but on my own laptop with the code, the docker-compose up works fine and start both my app and the database . do i need to transfer my source code and run docker-compose up from the other laptop

Comment: Using ```docker run``` will just run the docker container, this will ignore everything thats in your docker compose file. If you want you application to be abble to connect to the database using ```database:3306``` you need to run your docker compose file. The ```docker-compose up``` command assumes you have a ```docker-compose.yaml``` in the directory where you execute the command. So if you want to run your application on a different machine you need to share the ```docker-compose.yaml``` file

Comment: docker-compose automatically creates a docker network, allowing your containers to communicate. Alternatively you can create the network yourself, see: https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/ this way you could make it work without docker compose, however, this is more complicated

Comment: @Davidcloudobi if you want to share data, you should only have one database, i.e. one instance of mysql running. If your own image is a web application, then you probably also should only run one of those. If you run the images, then you need to make the URL of your web app available to your friend somehow.